# Read big-data(~300GB) quickly in Python

Tags: python, awk

I'm analyzing big data and raw data is .DAT file which is large(20~500GB).

.DAT file has 400 columns (with large number of rows) so I was used to using this command in linux(CentOS).

```
cat A.DAT | awk \'{FS="\x01"} {print $107, $108}\' > save.csv
```

Above process take about 8 mins. But I need more speed.

Is there any better way of extracting some columns in the .DAT file and read in Python?
(Better way compared to cat command?)

#### Added writing.

```
def read_file(read_name, save_name):
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"data",read_name+".DAT"), 'r', encoding='UTF8') as reading_file:
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"data",save_name+".csv"), 'w', encoding='UTF8') as saving_file:
        for read_row in reader(csv.reader(reading_file),delimiter="\x01"):
            saving_file.write(read_row[107]);saving_file.write(',');saving_file.write(read_row[108]);saving_file.write('\n')
```

Now I have coded like above it. (my 30GB .DAT file has 1,700,000 rows) and AWK command takes 8~11mins and above python code takes 8~9mins(My CPU is Intel Xeon series) in my current PC. 
Is there is any faster way than above python code? 
(Add) I'm now also searching about PyPy and multiprocessing

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also please provide a minimum of code that outlines what your trying to achieve. (What is $107, $108?)

Comment: The pure read time from an SSD for a 20GB file is about 40s. Don't expect it to get much faster than a minute.

Comment: for tathesse, Sorry for late, I coded my python code finally. It takes 8mins(for 30GB). but I have to daily analyze big data for 300GB... Any better way is exist? ($107 means my wanted column index)

Comment: Are you certain that AWK and Python took the same time (8 minutes)? Could you please try to look at the system load while running these processes? Specifically, look at disk (using iostat -x2 on Linux or iostat -w2 on Mac) and at CPU (using top on Linux / Mac).

Comment: Ok, I'm using server PC(CentOS) and will check about it when I available to use that public server for my company. AWK's process time for 30GB may differ to 2~13mins in my memory.

Comment: @INNOTECH Another question - in the awk code, the field separator is \x01, while in the python code it's \x75. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @INNOTECH so you're saying that AWK takes anywhere from 2 minutes to 13??? If that's the case, it seems that there are other things running on that machine. Could that be the case?

Comment: @Roy2012 A colleague from my company said that it only took 2 minutes with AWK to process 30 GB(I'm not sure about it). Since the server computer is in use, I connected to the server in remote by using putty and executed the above AWK command, sometimes it took 8 to13 minutes(I checked 5 times, but since I'm using putty and control the PC in remote, it may not the best performance). Python code took always 8 mins. The sperator actually uses \ x01 equally in the two codes above. Sorry.

Comment: 1) You could try reducing number of `write()` calls by calling it for `read_row[107] + ',' + ...`. 2) You could try reducing number of times you switch from reading to writing. In your case, you probably won't be able to load whole file to RAM, but you can read e.g. 1000 lines and remember info to be written and then do a single write command, and then read another 1000 lines.

Comment: @INNOTECH as mentioned above, I think the first step would be to get a stable environment to test against. Without it, you’ll see huge variations between different runs of the same implementation. The second step would be to understand where the bottleneck - whether it’s IO or CPU. Beyond that, Pypy and parallelism are great directions. Finally, if performance is critical here - why not just write a few lines of c?